# Is there a way to remove hemoglobin from pig kidney homogenate without deactivating enzymes?

Tags: kidney, centrifugation

I would like to measure different enzyme activities in centrifuged pig kidney homogenate. I get out of range errors at 450 nm. The samples are still reddish after centrifugation. Is there a way to remove hemoglobin without deactivating / removing enzymes? Thanks!